# How to add two thumbs on seek bar with custom progress drawable

Tags: android, seekbar

i want to add two thumbs on seek bar with custom progress drawable, I found 
[this](https://github.com/yahoo/android-range-seek-bar) or [this](https://github.com/yahoo/android-range-seek-bar) but they are not supporting custom progress drawable, So if any one know how to achieve this, Please let me know

Comment: I am not aware that this possible with `SeekBar`. There are several "range bar" implementations available that offer this sort of capability. [This Android Arsenal category](http://android-arsenal.com/tag/83) has those along with some other customized seek bars.

Comment: I dont think this is possible although i have created a simple library for the same purpose **RangeSeekBar** https://github.com/ranvijaySingh-Webonise/RangeSeekBar. Also there are other libraries available which offers a lot of customization. If you want to go for more interactive design then look for **Material Range Bar** http://android-arsenal.com/details/1/1272.